# Using Mockito to mock out Spring Boot repository delete call throws java.util.NoSuchElementException on get()

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I am new to Spring Boot and Mockito and having a problem mocking out a repository call in my service test.

I have a "delete" service method call as follows that I am trying to test with Mockito by mocking out the repository calls:

```
public interface IEntityTypeService {
    public EntityType getById(long id);
    public EntityType getByName(String name);
    public List<EntityType> getAll();
    public void update(EntityType entityType);
    public void delete(long id);
    public boolean add(EntityType entityType);
}

@Service
public class EntityTypeServiceImpl implements IEntityTypeService {
    @Autowired
    private EntityTypeRepository entityTypeRepository;

    @Override
    public void delete(long id) {
        entityTypeRepository.delete(getById(id));   
    }

    @Override
    public EntityType getById(long id) {
        return entityTypeRepository.findById(id).get();
    }

....implementation of other methods from the interface
}
```

My repository looks as follows:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface EntityTypeRepository extends LookupObjectRepository<EntityType> {

}
```

I have not implemented any of the methods in the repository as I am letting Spring Boot wire it up for me.

My test is as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class EntityTypeServiceTest {
    @TestConfiguration
    static class EntityTypeServiceImplTestContextConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public IEntityTypeService entityTypeService() {
            return new EntityTypeServiceImpl();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private IEntityTypeService entityTypeService;
    @MockBean
    private EntityTypeRepository entityTypeRepository;

    @Test
    public void whenDelete_thenObjectShouldBeDeleted() {                
        final EntityType entity = new EntityType(1L, "new OET");
        Mockito.when(entityTypeRepository.findById(1L).get()).thenReturn(entity).thenReturn(null);

        // when
        entityTypeService.delete(entity.getID());

        // then
        Mockito.verify(entityTypeRepository, times(1)).delete(entity);
        assertThat(entityTypeRepository.findById(1L).get()).isNull();       
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I get an error saying "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present"

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
    at xyz.unittests.service.EntityTypeServiceTest.whenDelete_thenObjectShouldBeDeleted(OriginatingEntityTypeServiceTest.java:41)
```

It references the line in the test saying `Mockito.when(originatingEntityTypeRepository.findById(1L).get()).thenReturn(entity).thenReturn(null);`

The reason I think I have to mock that call out is because the delete method in the Service calls the getById() method in the same service, which in turn calls entityTypeRepository.findById(id).get()

It is that, that I am assuming I have to mock out on the delete.  But clearly I am wrong.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Well entityTypeRepository.findById(1L) is not yet mocked and we called get() on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@Test
public void whenDelete_thenObjectShouldBeDeleted() {                
    final EntityType entity = new EntityType(1L, "new OET");
    Optional<EntityType> optionalEntityType = Optional.of(entity);
     Mockito.when(entityTypeRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(optionalEntityType);

    // when
    entityTypeService.delete(entity.getID());

    // then
    Mockito.verify(entityTypeRepository, times(1)).delete(entity);
    //I dont think you need to assert to confirm actual delete as you are testing mock registry. to assert somethink like below you need to return null by mocking the same call again and return the null but thats of no use
    //assertThat(entityTypeRepository.findById(1L).get()).isNull();       
 }
```

Updated your test. Basically we first need to mock the result of findById. refer my comment above asserting the actual delete.

Comment: Thank you bittu.  Much appreciated.  On your comment regarding not needing the assert.  It makes sense, but if I remove it, all I am testing is that the delete method is called once.  Seems like too basic a test really.  But perhaps that is all I need to do as the repository test should be the one testing that it is actually deleted from the DB.  I am just testing my logic here.

Comment: On a related, but different note, whilst I have your (or anybody elses) attention, do you by any chance know of a good example project I can pull from Github that uses Spring Boot with the normal tiers (domain, repository, service, controller) and has testing (unit and integration) with mocking?  I feel like this is something we all encounter and it would be great to have a "template" upon which to learn from somebody else?  Of course my use case is different, but that patterns will apply.